# Pulling a varbinary from a database and converting to a string

Tags: c#, sql

I'm pretty new to C# (As I'm sure you'll be able to tell) and I know this question has been asked a few times but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I'm trying to pull a `Varbinary(MAX)` value out of a database and store it as a string. I'm using a `SqlDataReader` for lifting some of the other columns out which works fine. All I'm using for them is `.ToString()`, but if I use `ToString()` for the Logo it returns `System.Byte[]`

```
    public TemplateData(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        initialiseData();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {

            Logo = dr["Logo"].ToString();
            TemplateId = dr["TemplateId"].ToString();
            Comment = dr["Comment"].ToString();
            SchemeCode = dr["SchemeCode"].ToString();
            Version = dr["Version"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

There is a plethora of issues I'm having aswell but I'll leave them for now.

Cheers!

Comment: What is the reason of storing `varbinary` as `string`, not as `byte[]`? Very strange design, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Cast as a byte array then convert, for example:

```
byte[] data = (byte[])row["BinaryColumn"];
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

However this is making the big assumption the binary *is* some kind of string, otherwise you might want Base-64:

```
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

Comment: Yeeaaah... Cheers for the quick response, but it's not working :(